# Convert string value to operator in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, operators

I'm trying to figure out a way to build a conditional dynamically.

Here is my code so far:

```csharp
var greaterThan = ">";
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

if (a Convert.ToOperator(greaterThan) b) {...}
```

I did read this post, but could not figure out how to implement some of the stuff: [C# convert a string for use in a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925886/c-convert-a-string-for-use-in-a-logical-condition)

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? The accepted answer *seems* straightforward.

Comment: You can consider using an expression evaluator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437964/best-and-shortest-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I wasn't going to post it, but thought that it might be of some help. Assuming of course that you don't need the advanced generic logic in Jon's post.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static Boolean Operator(this string logic, int x, int y)
    {
        switch (logic)
        {
            case ">": return x > y;
            case "<": return x < y;
            case "==": return x == y;
            default: throw new Exception("invalid logic");
        }
    }
}
```

You could use the code like this, with `greaterThan` being a `string` with the wanted logic/operator.

```
if (greaterThan.Operator(a, b))
```

Answer (score 16):

You can't really do that. The closest you could come would be:

```
Func<T, T, bool> ConvertToBinaryConditionOperator<T>(string op)
```

and then:

```
if (ConvertToBinaryConditionOperator<int>(input)(a, b))
{
}
```

The tricky bit is what `ConvertToBinaryConditionOperator` would do. You might want to look at [Marc Gravell's work on implementing generic operators in MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html). Expression trees could be really useful in this case, although I believe Marc has a working approach which works on .NET 2 as well.

So in this case you might have something like (using [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil))

```
public static Func<T, T, bool> ConvertToBinaryConditionOperator<T>(string op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case "<": return Operator.LessThan<T>;
        case ">": return Operator.GreaterThan<T>;
        case "==": return Operator.Equal<T>;
        case "<=": return Operator.LessThanOrEqual<T>;
        // etc
        default: throw new ArgumentException("op");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A more generic way of doing it is to take any IComparable objects.

```
    public static bool Compare<T>(string op, T left, T right) where T : IComparable<T> {
        switch (op) {
            case "<": return left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
            case ">": return left.CompareTo(right) > 0;
            case "<=": return left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
            case ">=": return left.CompareTo(right) >= 0;
            case "==": return left.Equals(right);
            case "!=": return !left.Equals(right);
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid comparison operator: {0}", op);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need to handle when left is null