# Construct evaluation condition dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net need help to resolve this:

Following is coming from database

```
Param1: 100
Param2: 184
Comparion Operator: >
```

In vb.net - i need to generate code like this:

```
If 100>184 Then
'Do something
Else
'Do something
End
```

I'm really struggling how to generate the above code in vb.net as values are coming from database.

I haven't tried anything, im struggling to write code for this.

Comment: Are you looking for a code-generation mechanism? or you are looking for a way to generate the code and run it on-the-fly? and What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rely on a set of conditions or a switch...case. You can get some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086058/convert-string-value-to-operator-in-c-sharp).

Thus, the solution for the specific case you are proposing should be something on the lines of:

```
Private Function checkSituation(ByVal val1 As Integer, ByVal inputOperator As String, ByVal val2 As Integer) As Boolean

    Select Case inputOperator
        Case ">"
            Return val1 > val2
        Case "<"
            Return val1 < val2
        Case "="
            Return val1 = val2
    End Select

End Function
```

In your case:

```
    If (checkSituation(100, ">", 184)) Then


    End If
```

Comment: I would add >=, <= and <> too.

Comment: This was just a sample code to provide some help. He should take it and create a code matching his exact expectations. He might want more things. But thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement a class `Comparator` that has a method which returns `true` if the condition is met and `false` if not. I'm not fluent in VB.NET, but I'd try the following in C#:

```
public static class Comparator
{
    public static bool Compare(int value1, int value2, string operator)
    {
        switch (operator)
        {
           case "<" : return value1 < value2;
           case "<=" : return value1 <= value2;
           case ">" : return value1 > value2;
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Private Function EvalData(param1 As Integer, param2 As Integer, operator As String) As Boolean
    Select Case operator
        Case ">" : Return param1 > param2
        Case "<" : Return param1 < param2
        Case "=" : Return param1 = param2
        Case Else 
            Throw New ApplicationException("No matches for this operator")
    End Select
End Function
```

And then use it in this way:

```
If EvalData(param1, param2, operator) Then
    'Do something
Else
    'Do something
End
```