# Use Operator from array in IF statement

Tags: c#

I am trying to use an operator which is selected from an array in an if statement. As the code is below I cannot compile it. Is there anyway around this ?

```
string[] operators = new string[]{"<",">","=","!="};

decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(values[j]);
var operator1 = (operators[Convert.ToInt32(IQueryTypeList[k])]);
int jjj = Convert.ToInt32(NTestValueList[k]);

if (value operator1 jjj)
{
    IsActive = true;
}
else
{
    IsActive = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `@value` is, but you can't use a string as the comparison operator in an `if` statement - you have to use the actual operator.

Comment: That was there by mistake, sorry, would it be possible to have an array of operators then ?

Comment: You can still use an array of operators, but you'll need to write logic using `if/else` or `switch` to determine what the operator is, and then in that block write the *proper* code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string value to operator in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086058/convert-string-value-to-operator-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to perform a string comparison with either an if-else chain or a switch statement. I don't know the exact syntax C#, so consider the following as pseudocode:

```
if (operator1.equals("<"))
    IsActive = value < jjj
// etc.
```

Comment: Ohh...that's a very elegant solution :)

Comment: That was the kind of thing I was looking for, Thank you.

Comment: @Tim Yah, I'm sure there are other, more elegant solutions. I'm a C# noob coming from Java. Of course, if this were part of a parser of some kind, I'd also build "node" classes which represent the operators in an abstract syntax tree. This would allow polymorphism rather than explicit `if` or `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply use the string as an operator but you could write an extension method for using strings. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086058/convert-string-value-to-operator-in-c-sharp) for more in-depth explanations.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch-case logic:

```
string[] operators = new string[]{"<",">","=","!="};
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(values[j]);
var operator1 = (operators[Convert.ToInt32(IQueryTypeList[k])]);
int jjj = Convert.ToInt32(NTestValueList[k]);

switch (operator1)
{
    case "<":
        //do something here
        break;
    case ">":
         //do something here
        break;
    case "=":
        //do something here
        break;
    case "!=":
        //do something here
        break;
}
```