# is it possible to do this if(zero suit.greater_than_or_equal_to 1)

Tags: c#

here's is my enum declaration

```
enum suit
        {
            greater_than = ">",
            Less_than = "<",
            greater_than_or_equal_to = ">=",
            less_than_or_equal_to = "<=",
        }
```

and i'm trying to do it like this but no luck.

```
int zero = 0;

 if(zero suit.greater_than_or_equal_to 1)
  {

  }
```

is there an other way it do it `in a word` not in like this `">="`?

Comment: is this your class mate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514333/turning-a-string-into-an-operator

Comment: not understand why you need do this, even not clear what you need.

Comment: it's just comes up in my mind if this is possible but got no luck for this.

Comment: But why go 100 miles to get a candy when its available right there at your street !

Comment: Got you @Jones Joseph but things comes up in my mind it's just the same as like >= than word.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522693/c-sharp-convert-string-to-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical operator can't be done in word's anymore.

> Even if you are thinking it's just the same but in reality it's
>   absolutely different.
>
> there's a lot of reason why the only thing i knew is its just work in
>   symbol sign and cannot be done in word.

Here's some [Logical Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the power of extension methods:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class Int32Extensions
    {
        public static bool IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(this int x, int y)
        {
            return x >= y;
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        internal static void Main()
        {
            if (17.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(42))
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this work if i'll do it like this int zero = 0;

            if(IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(int.Parse(zero.ToString()),15))
            {
                
            }

Comment: @redzsol It **is** a function. And it should work like `zero..IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(15)`. If it doesn't, you need to paste the error message. Most likely, your Visual Studio and .NET version are older than 5 years.