# What will be the type for operators?

Tags: c#, reflection, operators

I want to compare two values using operators and Reflection.

I would like to pass an expected value and the type of operator for dynamic comparison.

```
Dictionary<string,operator type> dict = new Dictionary<string,operator type>();
dict.Add("firstPropertyValue", >);
dict.Add("secondPropertyValue", !=);

void validate(Dictionary<string,operator type> temp)
{
   foreach(var item in temp)
   {
      if(actualvalue (item.value(operator)) item.key){//do something}
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

I will get the values of the properties at run time using Reflection, so I want the operator to be passed and do the validation at run time.

Comment: You'd have to create your own values to indicate which operator to use.  That or you could use `Func<string, string, bool>` and specify an operator with a lambda like `(s1, s2) => s1 != s2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086058/convert-string-value-to-operator-in-c-sharp

Comment: Check out the SO link above. Work with strings for the operators, then pass them through some c# logic to parse and perform actual comparisons based on the value of the string.

Comment: Do you only need to compare objects that implement IComparable, or do you actually want to invoke the operators?

Comment: @maricatch, Thanks for the suggestion. I will go through the link you have mentioned above

Comment: @Freggar, I want to actually want to invoke the operators. I am not sure about implementation of "IComparable".

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the use case but you might even be able to use a `List<Func<string, bool>>` then add stuff like `s => s > "firstPropertyValue"` and `s => s != secondPropertyValue`.

Comment: Your example is really confusing as I (kind of) understand what you want to do, but operators like `>` and `!=` need two operands, it isn't clear where the second one comes from.