# Convert string to C# Conditional operator

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I'd like convert string to ConditionalOperator, few sample :

- "and" to &&
- "or" to ||
- "greatherthan" to >=
- "contains" to .Contains

Something like this :

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static Operator ConditionalOperator(this string logic)
    {
        switch (logic)
        {
            case "and": return   // return && conditionaloperator
            case "or": return    // return || conditionaloperator
            case "greatherthan": return // return >= conditionaloperator
        }
    }
}
```

The second argument is not all the time a string but can be int, double, bool, ...

I'd like build something like  : `ConditionalOperator("==", "StringToSearch")` return a `Func<>`

Do you have an idea how to do this ?

Thanks,

Update 1, to clarify:
I received a list of object "Filter"[image]

The "FilterOperator" all possible values for a CondtionalOperator.

Comment: What is `Operator` or `Opertor`? What is the second argument?

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086058/convert-string-value-to-operator-in-c-sharp) might be of help to you.

Comment: @StephenRoss I read this post but I don't understand where "Operator" comes from Operator.LessThan<T>;

Comment: @shingo it's a typo

Comment: How would you do `Contains` with an `int`? Or a `bool`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics

```
public static bool Operator(string logic, T x, T y) where T : IComparable<T>
{
     var compare = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x, y);
     return logic switch
     {
         ">" => compare > 0,
         "<" => compare < 0,
         "==" => compare == 0,
         _ => throw new Exception("invalid logic"),
     };
 }
```

Optionally you could pass an explicit `IComparer`

```
public static bool Operator(string logic, T x, T y, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
     var compare = comparer.Compare(x, y);
     return logic switch
     {
         ">" => compare > 0,
         "<" => compare < 0,
         "==" => compare == 0,
         _ => throw new Exception("invalid logic"),
     };
 }
```

To return a `Func<T, T, bool>` you can just do

```
public static Func<T, T, bool> Operator(string logic, T x, T y, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
     return logic switch
     {
         ">" => (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0,
         "<" => (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x, y) < 0,
         "==" => (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x, y) == 0,
         _ => throw new Exception("invalid logic"),
     };
 }
```

For `string.Contains` you should probably make a separate overload just for `string`, as that cannot be genericized.

Comment: if there is Contains for a string ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Yes there is a `Contains` function, but that's not what you asked, and it wouldn't make sense to use that with generics. Perhaps you should make a separate overload just for `string`.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify. It's more create an expression.